# Why a template function accepts l-value to bind with r-value reference?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue

When I mark the function as template it accepts l-values to bind with r-values.

```
void func(int&& param){}

template<typename T> void t_func(T&& param){}

int main(){
  int a = 10;
  func(a); // error
  t_func(a); // no error
}
```

Why is `t_func` accepting l-values to  bind with r-value reference.

Comment: `T&&` can deduce reference types because of reference collapsing

Comment: Because it's not an r-value reference. It's a forwarding reference. `&&` in template deduction context is a forwarding reference, not an r-value reference. See the linked question for more information.

Comment: Thank you didnot know to what search to for. forwarding reference it is.